# Script isn't getting the innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML here

```
<div id="team_players">
  <h3>Players</h3>
  <button class="bold-btn" onclick="teamAct('player_list');">Refresh List ↻</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name(s)</th>
        <th>Inventory</th>
        <th>Playtime</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-player-ref="1">
        <td>Scriptist.<br>Scriptist.<br>HollowPresenter<br></td>
        <td><img src="img/item/item_shredder_g.png"><img src="img/item/block.png"></td>
        <td>4:13:20</td>
        <td><u style="color: #0F0">Online</u><u style="color: #0FF">Captain [1]</u><br><u style="color: #F00">Possible Alias of Snogg &lt;0&gt; [BANNED]</u></td>
        <td><br></td></tr><tr data-player-ref="13">
        <td>Snogg<br></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9:01</td>
        <td><u style="color: #F00">Banned</u><br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of HollowPresenter &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
        <td><button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('unban',13);">Un-Ban</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the innerHTML of the second `<td>` element. Here's my script below:

```
var Userinventory = document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-player-ref] > td:nth-of-type(2)' );

Userinventory.forEach(getinventoryitems)

function getinventoryitems(item, index) {
  var useritems = item.innerHTML[0];
  console.log(useritems);
}
```

Why won't this get the innerHTML? Which should return something like this

```
<td><img src="img/item/item_shredder_g.png"><img src="img/item/block.png"></td>
```

Comment: I get "undefined" in Google's console.

Comment: Voted to close as _"a problem that can no longer be reproduced"_. OP added an extra `[0]` to a property that generally doesn't have that, hence is more of a _"typo"_ issue and no real value for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extraneous `[0]` on the `.innerHTML`, which gets only the first character.

```js
var Userinventory = document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-player-ref] > td:nth-of-type(2)'); 
Userinventory.forEach(getinventoryitems)

function getinventoryitems(item, index) {
  var useritems = item.innerHTML;
  console.log(useritems);
}
```

```html
<div id="team_players">
  <h3>Players</h3>
  <button class="bold-btn" onclick="teamAct('player_list');">Refresh List ↻</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name(s)</th>
        <th>Inventory</th>
        <th>Playtime</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-player-ref="1">
        <td>Scriptist.<br>Scriptist.<br>HollowPresenter<br></td>
        <td><img src="img/item/item_shredder_g.png"><img src="img/item/block.png"></td>
        <td>4:13:20</td>
        <td><u style="color: #0F0">Online</u><u style="color: #0FF">Captain [1]</u><br><u style="color: #F00">Possible Alias of Snogg &lt;0&gt; [BANNED]</u></td>
        <td><br></td></tr><tr data-player-ref="13">
        <td>Snogg<br></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9:01</td>
        <td><u style="color: #F00">Banned</u><br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of HollowPresenter &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
        <td><button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('unban',13);">Un-Ban</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: When I remove it. The "[0]", It logs nothing at all. Just a blank box with no text. Not evening saying "undefined".

Comment: weird, I put it in a snippet and it shows that HTML being logged

Comment: well I copied it from before the edit. plus, it looks like that edit was all whitespace changes

Comment: It's not working. I noticed your anwser logs a single blank box as well.

Comment: just to make sure it's not some crazy browser thing, could you try doing `console.log('<b>aaa</b>');`?

Comment: I got it to log. It seems I need to display the element first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simplier way to do this,
with the corresponding javascript methods to acces html tables :

```
document.querySelector('table tbody').rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows

```js
console.log( document.querySelector('table tbody').rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML )
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<div id="team_players">
  <h3>Players</h3>
  <button class="bold-btn" onclick="teamAct('player_list');">Refresh List ↻</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name(s)</th>
        <th>Inventory</th>
        <th>Playtime</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-player-ref="1">
        <td>Scriptist.<br>Scriptist.<br>HollowPresenter<br></td>
        <td><img src="img/item/item_shredder_g.png"><img src="img/item/block.png"></td>
        <td>4:13:20</td>
        <td><u style="color: #0F0">Online</u><u style="color: #0FF">Captain [1]</u><br><u style="color: #F00">Possible Alias of Snogg &lt;0&gt; [BANNED]</u></td>
        <td><br></td></tr><tr data-player-ref="13">
        <td>Snogg<br></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>9:01</td>
        <td><u style="color: #F00">Banned</u><br><u style="color: #FFF">Possible Alias of HollowPresenter &lt;0&gt;</u></td>
        <td><button class="btn-small btn-orange" onclick="teamAct('unban',13);">Un-Ban</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```